# Switch Multiple view controllers in a Single View controller iOS

Tags: ios, uicontainerview

I'd would like to display static controls(4 Buttons at the bottom & NotificationBar at the top) all over the screens. These controls should be available in all screens.

I want to show the corresponding pages (when clicked) in between these two controls. (i.e.,) between Notification Bar and buttons.

So how can i do that?

I don't want to add those controls in each and every view controllers which makes more complex.

I got a idea of Implementing Container view. But Don't know whether it's the proper solution for my problem. So kindly suggest me to resolve my problem?

The layout is given below:

---

```
                Notification Bar
```

---

<<<<<<<<< Corresponding Page to display>>>>>>>>>>

---

Button 1     Button 2     Button3      Button4

---

So suggest me to resolve this?

Answer (score 2):

If your content views are the view of UIViewController, when you do addSubview:, please try the following code:

```
[controller willMoveToParentViewController:_containerViewController];
[_containerViewController.view addSubview:controller.view];
[_containerViewController addChildViewController:controller];
```

And if you remove some view of view controller from its super view, you should do:

`[controller removeFromParentViewController];`

`[controller.view removeFromSuperview];`

`[controller willMoveToParentViewController:nil];`

Such way can make your appearance method of UIViewController be called properly.

Comment: Thanks for your response. Can you explain in detail..?

Comment: willMoveToParentViewController: & didMoveToParentViewController: should be paired in fact. But addChildViewController: will do didMoveXXXX  and removeFromXXX: will do willMoveXXX:, so you just need to do as above. You can see the detail in apple doc under the discussion of didMoveToParentViewController: method.

Answer (score 0):

Here's the scenario :

1. Put a different tag (from 0 to 3) to your buttons
2. Link your buttons with the same `IBAction`
3. In your top controller, store each viewController in an array
4. In the `IBAction` method, call `[_myViewControllersArray objectAtIndex:button.tag];`  and display the corresponding view.
5. User `[_containerView addSubview:controller.view];`

Comment: Hope, it could solve my problem. I'll try this solution. Thanks...:)

Comment: So, is it fitting with your needs ?